# AlarmManager set Alarm for Weekly Repeated On Selected Days

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I am Creating Alarm Application with Setting Alarm of Multiple Days i.e Repeating Alarm.My Android Alarm Application View Like This,[image]

i Have Done Code for this,

```
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(ALARM_ACTION_NAME);

alarmIntent.putExtra("AlarmID", m_alarmId);

PendingIntent alarmPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, m_alarmId, alarmIntent, 0);    

//listofred is a ArrayList of int items.contains int valye for selected days...for My Example listofred:3,4,5,7 
for (int i = 0; i < listOfred.size(); i++) {

                // for alarm ...
                calNow = Calendar.getInstance();
                calSet = (Calendar) calNow.clone();

                int day = calSet.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);  //current day...for example.13 dec 2014 - sat  so, day = 7     

                calSet.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, listOfred.get(i));
                calSet.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, time_picker.getCurrentHour());
                calSet.set(Calendar.MINUTE, time_picker.getCurrentMinute());
                calSet.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
                calSet.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);


                alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                        calSet.getTimeInMillis(), (DateUtils.DAY_IN_MILLIS)*7,
                        alarmPI);

                //parameter long intervalMillis.....(DateUtils.DAY_IN_MILLIS)*7 so that it will repeat after each 7 days...


            }
```

My Problem is When i run this code it will set repeat alarm for only Saturday(**i.e last object in listofred Arraylist**) every time it set alarm for last object in Arraylist.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14272295/how-can-i-get-the-repeat-alarm-for-week-days-using-alarm-manager

Comment: Set the alarm to repeat every day and have the `BroadcastReceiver` check if it's one of the 'red' days or not. If it is then do whatever you want it to do - if not, do nothing.

Comment: Hi @Rahul, can you please share the code ho you calculated remaining time?

Answer (score 1):

I know it is quite late to answer this, but isn't it because of the same pending intent being passed to each alarm event.
Perhaps this might help.

```
 PendingIntent alarmPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, m_alarmId, alarmIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3009690/1111127